# Regarding ANCOVA and regression

Tags: regression, ancova

So i have a question with 1 continuous independent variable, 1 continuous dependent variable, 1 continuous co-variate while controlling for a categorical variable.

So i know analysis of co-variate is probably out of the question because of the continuous IV and i will probably have to use a regression.

Can anyone help with how i should do a regression with these 4 variables?

Answer (score 1):

ANCOVA is not out of the question - that's just the situation it was intended for.

ANOVA, ANCOVA and multiple regression are all the same model.

Questions about how to code are off topic here, and you don't even say what programming language you use. But all statistical packages will have methods for multiple regression. If you need help, look at user manuals or at sites devoted to the package you are using.

Comment: Since im going for a full model so currently im doing a multiple regression on SPSS with IV, covariate, and controlling variable with the addition of a interaction term using the 'compute variable' function. Do you think this is a good way to do it?

Comment: I don't know SPSS, so I can't help with that, but it sounds right.